# Method parametrized with one type accepts two types

Tags: java, generics, methods

Probably I am missing something and maybe my assumptions were wrong, but I thought that when I declare parametrized method with type `T` then no matter how much variables there are with that type it is still the same type. But I see that this compiles and it oposses my view.

```
static <T> void f(T a, T b) { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(Integer.MIN_VALUE, "...");
}
```

So if my method is parametrized with one type and I am using that one type in two paramteres why does it allow me to send two objects with two totally different types? I guess it comes down to treating `T` as `Object`?

Comment: "I guess it comes down to treating T as Object?" Yes. You may as well just declare `static void f(Object a, Object b) {}`.

Comment: Even more funny, type erasure will erase even constructs like `static <T, S extends T> void f(T a, S b) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Integer and String are two different types, they still share a common super-type. `Serializable`.

To verify this, lets return `T`,

```
static <T> T f(T a, T b) {
    return null;
}
Serializable s = f(Integer.MIN_VALUE, "..."); // compiles
```

The compiler will resolve (or infer, not sure about the technical term) to the most specific type. For example,

```
Number number = f(Integer.MAX_VALUE, BigDecimal.ONE);
```

Now, the type resolved is `Number` because both types are subtypes of `Number`,as well as `Serializable`, as well as `Object` of course.

Comment: I believe the common super type is actually `Object`. It compiles fine on two instances of classes that do not have a common super type other than `Object`.

Comment: @Casey plz check my edit. Of course Object is common, but Serializable is more specific